# NPE thrown at fragment change (can't address fragment.getView())

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

So this is my fPretraga class:

```
public class FragmentPretraga extends android.app.Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.izgled_pretraga, container, false);
    }
}
```

And this is the function

```
try
        {
            Spinner oblasti = (Spinner) fPretraga.getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerOblasti);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.oblasti, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            oblasti.setAdapter(adapter);
            EditText sranje = (EditText) fPretraga.getView().findViewById(R.id.editBrojDjaka);
            sranje.setText("0");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.e("LOAD_TAG","Šta se desilo?",e);
        }
```

The function is supposed to load the variables (in this case inflate the Spinner with a preset array of string values and set the text of one textbox to its default "0" value). My assumption is that NPE is thrown because the getView() doesn't return the View I was expecting i.e. the onCreateView I wrote is wrong. Because the id "spinnerOblasti" exists within the "izgled_pretraga.xml" file. Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

LogCat log:

> 04-16 14:17:19.866: D/gralloc_goldfish(541): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541): Šta se desilo?
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at com.markosoft.maturko.Maturko.UcitajPromenljive(Maturko.java:214)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at com.markosoft.maturko.Maturko$MyTabListener.onTabSelected(Maturko.java:181)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:512)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:893)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:488)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.356: E/LOAD_TAG(541):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 04-16 14:18:50.746: D/dalvikvm(541): GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 4% free 10102K/10439K, paused 3ms+4ms

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: Where does the second chunk of code reside?

Comment: Try `getActivity()` instead of `getView()`

Comment: @SankarV just a moment
Egor it's within a function that's called when different tab is selected.
TronicZomB Tried it, but that' even more wrong ;)

Comment: To diagnose it I'd remove the `catch (NullException e)` part and just let it crash. And then I'd post the resulting logcat. My guess is you don't have `android.R.layout.simple_spinner`_dropdown_item in your layout. But it's just a guess.

Comment: That is true, but I thought it's part of Android APIs. Eclipse didn't show a missing resource or identifier error when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView you must do this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.izgled_pretraga, null);
oblasti =(Spinner)  view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOblasti);
return view;
```

And then you can call spinner everywhere...

Comment: You want from fragment activity to set views? In which line it breaks?